# В чем разница между module.exports & exports.property ?

Tags: node.js

Привет . При создании модулей всегда использовал exports.property :

```
 exports.boo = {name:'dexter',
getSerial:function(){
    return this.name
}}

var fn = require('./file.js');
console.log( fn.boo.getSerial() );
```

Н также встретил такого зверя как module.exports :

```
module.exports = function(){
    console.log('super log')
}
var fn = require('./file.js');

fn();
```

Второй способ является единственным вариантом возврата функции с модуля (первый способ вернет ошибку) .
Меня интересует что это за module.exports ? Какие его еще особенности нужно помнить?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

тут говорится о том, что exports это изначально module.exports (объект) а exports=function() {} не работает, потому-что вы переопределяете переменную и ссылка теряется таким образом.

т.е. на самом деле код который использует просто exports выглядит так:

```
var exports=module.exports={};
exports.method1=function() {};
```

теперь представьте, что следующей строкой написано:

```
console.log(exports,module.exports); //{method1: function},{method1: function}
exports=function() {}; 
console.log(exports,module.exports); //function(){},{method1: function}
```

но require как раз возвращает module.exports (да он и не может вернуть просто exports, т.к. ссылок на нее нет)

Answer (score 3):

exports изначально является алиасом для module.exports и оба ссылаются на **один и тот же** пустой объект.

Внутри node.js это выглядит так:

```
var exports=module.exports={};
```

Но функция require(path) возвращает именно module.exports.

Иногда может быть так, что вы не хотите, чтобы ваш модуль ссылался на пустой объект, а хотите, чтобы ваш модуль ссылался на экземпляр другого класса. Чтобы сделать так, нужно этот экземпляр класса назначить на module.exports

```
//a.js

var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
module.exports = new EventEmitter();

// Do some work, and after some time emit
// the 'ready' event from the module itself.
setTimeout(function() {
  module.exports.emit('ready');
}, 1000);
```

Тогда из другого файла, мы можем сделать

```
var a = require('./a');
a.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('module a is ready');
});
```

Обратите внимание, что так сделать нельзя

```
//a.js

var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
exports = new EventEmitter();
...
```

Так как теперь, вы переопределили переменную exports, то exports и module.exports ссылаются на **разные данные**. exports ссылается на new EventEmitter(); в то время, как module.exports до сих пор ссылается на пустой объект {}. А так как require(path) возвращает module.exports, то вернется пустой объект. Поэтому перезаписывать exports не имеет смысла, это изначально всего лишь алиас.

В общем module.exports нужен тогда, когда вы хотите вместо объекта вернуть какой-то другой тип данных, например массив

```
module.exports = ['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3'];
```

или строку

```
module.exports = 'string';
```

или уже упомянутый экземпляр другого класса

```
module.exports = new EventEmitter();
```

А если же вы просто хотите добавить свойства и методы к пустому объекту {}, то в таком случае, можно использовать просто exports.property

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле не единственный. Еще один способ возврата функции такой:

```
exports.boo = {name:'dexter',
getSerial:function(){
return this.name
 }}

var fn = require('./file.js');

console.log( exports.boo.getSerial());
```